# asp.net core ControllerBase.User without implementing Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Im trying to get an Access token, and to do it I need this line:

```
 string userId = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
```

However, unless I Implement `Controller` it cannot find `User`. I've tried `HttpContext.User` And a few other things as well.

It comes from `ControllerBase` and looks like `public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }`. Is there no way to get this in a normal class with an import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and access the user like this

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
```